# Icon on About page missing on iPad with iOS 7

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ipad

The icon on the about page is missing on the iPad (iOS7). iPhone with iOS8 is working fine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Icon also missing on iPad with iOS 8.0. Stack Exchange iOS App Version 1.1.0.118.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch – this is something that we've noticed but keep putting off.

It will be fixed in next beta update, on version **1.1.0.120**